# How do I divide a canvas into 9 equal squares in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I tried to create an image in photoshop with 9 equal squares and I failed horribly. Is there a simple way to divide a canvas into equal sizes rectangles without having to work out the numbers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You can use [guideguide](http://guideguide.me) . It's a quite simple extension that you can install on photoshop. From then on just make columns(3) and lines(3) (in your case) and you have your 9 spaces in your canvas.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**:
Curently PS CC 2017 as a "New Guide Layout" under `View > New Guide Layout`, that allows to do the same as guideguide, though not so fast.

Comment: Thanks! it was really helpful!

Answer (score 28):

### For Photoshop CS6 or older

Choose `View > New Guide`, Click `Vertical`, Enter 33.33%, hit OK.

Choose `View > New Guide`, Click `Vertical`, Enter 66.66% hit OK.

Choose `View > New Guide`, Click `Horizontal`, Enter 33.33%, hit OK.

Choose `View > New Guide`, Click `Horizontal`, Enter 66.66% hit OK.

### For Photoshop CC or newer

Choose `View > New Guide Layout...` and enter the 3 columns and 3 rows, hit OK.

Comment: Or just use `view > New Guide Layout...`

Comment: @Mat did you miss the last line of this answer???

Answer (score 12):

Right click on the crop tool, choose the slice select tool, right click on the image, divide slice, insert the vertical and horizontal number of slices and it is done...

Comment: This is the right answer, as the question specifically asks for not working out numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Here it is. You should use slice tool, to slice the image. You can find full guide in below video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02FBnJB6k0Q

1. Open the image file.  Menu >  File > open
2. Select "Slice Tool" from Tool box
3. Right click on "Slice Tool", there are 3 options. Click on "Select slice tool"
4. You will see, small rectangle icon on the left corner of image
5. Right click on rectangle icon. Click on "Divide slice" option
6. A box of "Divide slice" will open. You will see 2 options. Horizontally and vertically
7. Select any of them or both.
8. Now you will find that, image is of equal size.
9. Save the image. You are done

Answer (score 4):

Go to the top menu in Photoshop and select: `Edit > Preferences > Guides, Grids & Slices`. In the preferences box that appears, go to the third option, "Grid". There's a label for "Gridline Every:" with a text box and a drop down menu. Enter `33.33` in the text box and choose "Percent" from the drop down menu. For "Subdivisions" choose `1`.

Then show your gridlines. You can do this by going to the top menu and choosing `View > Show > Grid` or clicking CNTRL and the quote key on your keyboard (in Windows). This will show your grid with nine equal sized squares. Technically there will be a tiny amount of extra space (maybe 1-2 pixels) on the bottom row and right column.

You can add guides on those gridlines or you can just add your squares there.